# Playing local videos on Webview in Xamarin IOS by HTML5Player - file:// protocol is not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, video, webview, local

I'm building a native App with Xamarin for IOS and Windows. This App includes a Webview which should play some local video files. For this I use the HTML5 video player and set the ***src*** property with the local path of the video. For Windows it already works with ***"ms-appdata:///local/" + directory***. But I found no way to implement a synonym way for IOS. I've already tried with ***file:///var/mobile/Applications/..*** but it did not work. Please help me, I really don't know how to do this.

Typescript code to set the src path for windows and IOS:

```
if (isIOSPlatform == "false") {
                for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
                    media[i].directory = "ms-appdata:///local/" + media[i].directory + "/" + media[i].fileName;
                }

            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
                    media[i].directory = "file://" + folderPath + "/" + media[i].directory + media[i].fileName;
                }

                let galleryVideoPopup = new GalleryVideoPopup(media);
                galleryVideoPopup.onVideoDeleted = (media: Media) => this.onMediaDeleted(media, part, mediaType);
                galleryVideoPopup.show();
            }
```

JQueryCode for the popUp and the video tag which is included:

```
show() {
    $("#popup").dxPopup({
        contentTemplate: (contentElement: JQuery) => {
            this.galleryElement = $("<div>", { id: "item-photo-video-gallery" }).dxGallery({
                dataSource: this.media,
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                itemTemplate: (data: any, index: number, element: JQuery) => {
                    element.append($("<video>", {
                        src: data.directory,
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "100%",
                        controls: true,
                        type: "video/mp4"
                    }));
                }
            });
            contentElement.append(this.galleryElement);

            let deleteButton = $("<div>", { id: "item-delete-button" }).dxButton({
                icon: "fa fa-trash",
                onClick: (e) => this.onDeleteVideo()
            });

            contentElement.append(deleteButton);

            return contentElement;
        },
        width: "60%",
        height: "60%",
        title: "Video",
        closeOnOutsideClick: true
    }).dxPopup("instance").show();
}
```

And here is a photo that shows that the video is not play:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DLzN.jpg)

Comment: Where did you place the video file in ios application?

Comment: I used a meda library which recorded the video and placed it in the /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application project folder..